# How do I hide pandas to_datetime NaT in when I write to CSV?

Tags: python, date, pandas

I am a little bit perplexed as to why NaT are showing up in my CSV...usually they show up as "".  Here is my date formatting:

```
df['submitted_on'] = pd.to_datetime(df['submitted_on'], errors='coerce').dt.to_period('d')
df['resolved_on'] = pd.to_datetime(df['resolved_on'], errors='coerce').dt.to_period('d')
df['closed_on'] = pd.to_datetime(df['closed_on'], errors='coerce').dt.to_period('d')
df['duplicate_on'] = pd.to_datetime(df['duplicate_on'], errors='coerce').dt.to_period('d')
df['junked_on'] = pd.to_datetime(df['junked_on'], errors='coerce').dt.to_period('d')
df['unproducible_on'] = pd.to_datetime(df['unproducible_on'], errors='coerce').dt.to_period('d')
df['verified_on'] = pd.to_datetime(df['verified_on'], errors='coerce').dt.to_period('d')
```

When I df.head() this is my result.  Good, fine, all is dandy.

```
  identifier status submitted_on resolved_on closed_on duplicate_on junked_on  \
0        xx1      D   2004-07-28         NaT       NaT   2004-08-26       NaT   
1        xx2      N   2010-03-02         NaT       NaT          NaT       NaT   
2        xx3      U   2005-10-26         NaT       NaT          NaT       NaT   
3        xx4      V   2006-06-30  2006-09-15       NaT          NaT       NaT   
4        xx5      R   2012-09-21  2013-06-06       NaT          NaT       NaT   

  unproducible_on verified_on  
0             NaT         NaT  
1             NaT         NaT  
2      2005-11-01         NaT  
3             NaT  2006-11-20  
4             NaT         NaT
```

But I write to CSV and the NaT shows up:

```
"identifier","status","submitted_on","resolved_on","closed_on","duplicate_on","junked_on","unproducible_on","verified_on"
"xx1","D","2004-07-28","NaT","NaT","2004-08-26","NaT","NaT","NaT"
"xx2","N","2010-03-02","NaT","NaT","NaT","NaT","NaT","NaT"
"xx3","U","2005-10-26","NaT","NaT","NaT","NaT","2005-11-01","NaT"
"xx4","V","2006-06-30","2006-09-15","NaT","NaT","NaT","NaT","2006-11-20"
"xx5","R","2012-09-21","2013-06-06","NaT","NaT","NaT","NaT","NaT"
"xx6","D","2009-11-25","NaT","NaT","2010-02-26","NaT","NaT","NaT"
"xx7","D","2003-08-29","NaT","NaT","2003-08-29","NaT","NaT","NaT"
"xx8","R","2003-06-06","2003-06-24","NaT","NaT","NaT","NaT","NaT"
"xx9","R","2004-11-05","2004-11-15","NaT","NaT","NaT","NaT","NaT"
"xx10","R","2008-02-21","2008-09-25","NaT","NaT","NaT","NaT","NaT"
"xx11","R","2007-03-08","2007-03-21","NaT","NaT","NaT","NaT","NaT"
"xx12","R","2011-08-22","2012-06-21","NaT","NaT","NaT","NaT","NaT"
"xx13","J","2003-07-07","NaT","NaT","NaT","2003-07-10","NaT","NaT"
"xx14","A","2008-09-24","NaT","NaT","NaT","NaT","NaT","NaT"
```

So, I did what I thought would fix the problem.  `df.fillna('', inplace=True)` and nada.  I then tried `df.replace(pd.NaT, '')` with no results, followed by `na_rep=''` when I wrote to CSV which also did not result in desired output.  What am I supposed to be using to prevent NaT from being transcribed into CSV?

Sample data:

```
"identifier","status","submitted_on","resolved_on","closed_on","duplicate_on","junked_on","unproducible_on","verified_on"
"xx1","D","2004-07-28 07:00:00.0","null","null","2004-08-26 07:00:00.0","null","null","null"
"xx2","N","2010-03-02 03:00:16.0","null","null","null","null","null","null"
"xx3","U","2005-10-26 14:20:20.0","null","null","null","null","2005-11-01 13:02:22.0","null"
"xx4","V","2006-06-30 07:00:00.0","2006-09-15 07:00:00.0","null","null","null","null","2006-11-20 08:00:00.0"
"xx5","R","2012-09-21 06:30:58.0","2013-06-06 09:35:25.0","null","null","null","null","null"
"xx6","D","2009-11-25 02:16:03.0","null","null","2010-02-26 12:28:22.0","null","null","null"
"xx7","D","2003-08-29 07:00:00.0","null","null","2003-08-29 07:00:00.0","null","null","null"
"xx8","R","2003-06-06 12:00:00.0","2003-06-24 12:00:00.0","null","null","null","null","null"
"xx9","R","2004-11-05 08:00:00.0","2004-11-15 08:00:00.0","null","null","null","null","null"
"xx10","R","2008-02-21 05:13:39.0","2008-09-25 17:20:57.0","null","null","null","null","null"
"xx11","R","2007-03-08 17:47:44.0","2007-03-21 23:47:57.0","null","null","null","null","null"
"xx12","R","2011-08-22 19:50:25.0","2012-06-21 05:52:12.0","null","null","null","null","null"
"xx13","J","2003-07-07 12:00:00.0","null","null","null","2003-07-10 12:00:00.0","null","null"
"xx14","A","2008-09-24 11:36:34.0","null","null","null","null","null","null"
```

Comment: Are you sure those are actual NaTs? Can they be regular strings ('NaT')? I tried with your dataset, replaced 'NaT' with pd.NaT and it wrote to CSV correctly. What is your pandas version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem lies in that you are converting to `periods`.  The `NaT` you see is actually a `period` object.

One way around this is to convert to strings instead.

Use

```
.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Instead of

```
.dt.to_period('d')
```

Then the `NaT`s you see will be strings and can be replaced like

```
.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').replace('NaT', '')
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(date=pd.to_datetime(['2015-01-01', pd.NaT])))
df
```

[image]

```
df.date.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

0    2015-01-01
1           NaT
Name: date, dtype: object
```

---

```
df.date.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').replace('NaT', '')

0    2015-01-01
1              
Name: date, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks, once again @piRsquared.  

Do you know of any excellent books that cover a-z of pandas?